# Delete local files after success FTP transfer

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am writing a batch file that will do the following:

1. Connect to remote FTP site
2. Push all files from local director to remote FTP site
3. Disconnet

This works fine, **but** I also want to empty the local directory after upload (otherwise they will be transferred everytime). Unfortunately I have a problem where the connection to side might not always be possible, and thus if I add a crude del *.* to the end of my batch file, it will delete the files even if they havent been uploaded.

Can anyone think of a way around this? i.e. If file uploaded then delete.

```
    @echo off
cd \
cd c:\temp
echo user bacon> ftpcmd.dat
echo eggs>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put *.xls>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bye>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat <Server>
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems ftp command does not return an errorlevel on which to operate, so best option is to redirect output of ftp command to a file and use findstr to check for errors in output.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows FTP command does not provide a method to guarantee the file is complete.

A command line FTP transfer could fail and you will have a truncated file and FTP doesn't provide a method to detect this.